# .mp4 video doesn't work on my web page

Tags: html5-video, mp4

I tried to add a .mp4 video on my web page. And it doesn't work, I got an error in firebug. Bellow is the code:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source type="video/mp4" src="08.mp4" >
</video>
```

Error:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/08.mp4"
HTTP load failed with status 404. Load of media resource http://localhost/08.mp4 failed.
All candidate resources failed to load. Media load paused.
```

I tried with a .m4v video, and it works fine:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source type="video/mp4" src="Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer.m4v" >
</video>
```

If I tried to access http://localhost/08.mp4 I got the following:

```
A 404 error occurred
Page not found.

The requested URL could not be matched by routing.
No Exception available
```

Both videos are in the same folder.
Codec information: [image]
Can you tell me please where is the problem?

Comment: You have both video files in the same folder? And with the same code it worked for the .m4v but not for the mp4? Try to rename it.

Comment: Yes, the both videos are in the same folder. The same code. For .m4v it works and for the .mp4 don't

Comment: Try renaming `08.mp4` to `test.m4v` or something

Comment: The same error in firebug: "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/test.m4v"

Comment: Have you tried other browsers than firefox?

Comment: Yes: Chrome and IE11. The same in both

Comment: Have you compared codec information e.g. in vlc?

Comment: I just tried to open the video with vlc and it works. Where can I find codec information?

Comment: Video --> Codec information afaik. Not hard to find

Comment: I attached a image with codec information

Comment: I would now compare it with the working video's codec

Comment: I solved the problem. Because I use zend2 framework the folder with video should be in the public folder. Now I moved it, and it works

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.
Because I use zend2 framework the folder with video should be in the public folder. 
First I put the video in other folder, now I moved it in public and works fine.